# Find n largest values in a column 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find the n largest numbers in a particular column in SQL Server.

We can find the largest value in a column and the 2nd largest value easily.

But how do I find say, 5 largest values in a column ?

Comment: How do you find the largest and second largest in such a way that can't be trivially modified to find the next 3 items?

Comment: Hi. thanks for the replies, sorry I am using mysql, and I got the ans now.
I used the following query, "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tbl_PRODUCT ORDER BY items_sold DESC;"

Comment: I used it this way: "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tbl_PRODUCT ORDER BY items_sold DESC;" Now I have a foreign key in my table, (family_ID) I want to find the columns with the max value, but they should have diff family_ID ie, i find the largest of all products under family_ID: 1, then i want the largets of all under family_ID 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySql you can use [`[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count }]`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/81614) to do this like so:

```
...
ORDER BY SomeField DESC
LIMIT @n;
```

For SQL Server you can use the `TOP(n)` to get the top n:

```
SELECT TOP(@n) SomeFieldName
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY SomeField DESC
```

For example:

```
SELECT TOP 5 items_sold
FROM tbl_PRODUCT 
ORDER BY items_sold dESC
```

**Update:** If you have another table `families` with a foreign key `family_ID` to products table, and  you want to find all products with the top n family id's. Then you can dot this:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM Products WHERE family_ID  IN
   (
       SELECT TOP 5 family_ID
       FROM families
       ORDER BY family_ID DESC
   )
```

**Update 2**: The topmost product in each family:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY family_ID ORDER BY items_sold DESC) row_num
    FROM @Products
)
SELECT * FROM cte
where row_num = 1
Order by family_ID
```

### [Here is alive demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/81614)

Comment: SELECT TOP 5
FROM tbl_PRODUCT 
ORDER BY items_sold
is this not right? I am getting an error, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'."

Comment: @pseudoname Sorry you need to specify the column you want to select for example `ItemID` or `ItemPrice` for example. See my edit

Comment: Thanks for you answer Mahmoud, it worked, I used it this way:
"SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tbl_PRODUCT ORDER BY items_sold DESC;"

Now I have a foreign key in my table, say family_ID
I want to find the columns with the max value, but they should have diff family_ID
ie, i find the largest of all products under family_ID: 1, then i want the largets of all under family_ID 2

Comment: @pseudoname - So you had another table `families` with a foreign key `family_ID` to products table right? and  you want to find all products under the top n family id's right?

Comment: ie, I want the topmost product in each family

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud Gamal, can you please help ?

Comment: @pseudoname - Absolutely, I just was setting a [live demo here for you](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/81614). `the topmost product in each family ` added. See my edit

Answer (score 3):

You tagged this both for MySQL and SQL Server.  In SQL Server you can use [`TOP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP 5 yourColumn
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY someColumn DESC;
```

`TOP` limits the number of rows returned.  To get the data with the largest/smallest values you will want to include an `ORDER BY`.

In MySQL you will use [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Another way to do this in SQL Server is using `row_number()`:

```
select id
from 
(
  select id, row_number() over(order by id desc) rn
  from yourtable
) x
where rn <= 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5755/4)

Answer (score 0):

sql server

```
select min(val)
 from your_table
where val in (select top 5 val from your_table  order by val desc)
```

mysql

```
select min(val)
 from your_table
where val in (select val from your_table  order by val desc limit 5)
```