# Finding N Largest elements in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, top-n

I have a **city** table comprising of fields such as `ID`, `Name`, `CountryCode` and `Population`. I want to find the top N(say N = 5) cities with the largest `Population`.

A very naive way would be to find the city with the largest population using the `MAX()` group function, and finding the rest via a variant of the method mentioned here.

[What is the simplest SQL Query to find the second largest value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100/what-is-the-simplest-sql-query-to-find-the-second-largest-value)

Does anyone know of a better method to achieve the goal?

Comment: why dont order by population in descending and put limit N ? , that will give you N largest cities by population.

Comment: There is not necessarily such a thing as "the" top N cities. There could be more than N tied, and there could be fewer. PS Apparently you haven't even tried googling 'stackoverflow sql' with your question title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find n largest values in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705789/find-n-largest-values-in-a-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the top N cities, using `order by` and `limit` would be a much simpler approach:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     city
ORDER BY population DESC
LIMIT    5 -- or any other N
```

Comment: Be careful if there are multiple rows with the same population. LIMIT may not give the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM cities AS c1
WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM cities AS c2
 WHERE c2.population > c1.population)<5;
```

This query may return more than five rows if there are several cities with the same population. You didn't specify what result you expect for "top 5" when there are tied values.